# Google Fiber coming soon!

Tags: file, file-transfer

Hey everyone!

So Google is going to start providing internet in the near future!  Here are the details.  I am curious as to how this will help audio recording sessions between multiple people across the country and even the world.

What are some practical reason why you think Google fiber will help you in the audio world.  Please don't say bit torrents!

https://fiber.google.com/about/

Answer (score 1):

The bandwidth could definitely benefit creating audio or music collaboratively over distance. Many modern DAWs (Reaper, Ohm Studio, Bitwig) have introduced networking specifically for this.

The other thing is, will people want to work remotely other than for fun? At least it's (IMO) a quite powerful option even for professional collaboration.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with people remotely, handing off sessions with notes to continue workflow, uploaded bounces from Pro Tools for producers and directors and even uploaded various SFX on Dropbox to friends and editors. Having something like this would be a godsend and would benefit tons of people if this was to spread all over the nation.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished a job for an animation in denmark. So much dropbox my internet was constantly stuffed with UL / DL. This IS a godsend.